# There is no argument given that corresponding to the required parameter error

Tags: c#

I am creating a code which ask the users input for its first name, last name, hours, and wages. Then the hours and wages are then calculated and will be shown when called. Now I got this error
"**There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'input 1' of 'Human.Human(string,string)**"
shown on what should I change or what constructors do I  need to fix?

```
    using EncapsulationConcept;
    using System;

    namespace EncapsulationConcept
    {
    class Human
    {
    private string value1;
    private string value2;

    public Human(string input1, string input2)
    {
        value1 = input1;
        value2 = input2;
    }
    public void DisplayInfo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nfirst name is: {0}", value1);
        Console.WriteLine("last name is: {0}", value2);
    }
}
class Worker : Human
{
    private int Hours;
    private int wages = 50;
    private int result;
    public  int HourlyWage(int hour)
    {
        Hours = hour;
        result = hour * wages;
        return hour;
    }
    public void DisplayInfo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nNo. of hours in {0}", result);
    }
}
   }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input1, input2;
        int hour;

        Console.Write("First name : ");
        input1 = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Last name: ");
        input2 =  Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter hours : ");
        hour = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
       
        Human human = new Human(input1, input2);
        human.DisplayInfo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The error is telling you that the `Worker` class can't be created because it has no way to create the underlying `Human` type.  `Human` has a constructor with parameters:

```
public Human(string input1, string input2)
```

But `Worker` does not.  So if you were to do `new Worker()` then the code has no way to supply those parameters to `Human`.

You'd either need to allow a parameterless `Human`:

```
public Human() { }
```

Or add a `Worker` constructor which provides parameters to `Human`:

```
public Worker(string input1, string input2) : base(input1, input2) { }
```

However you do it, any time you create an instance of an inherited type it needs to be able to create an instance of the underlying base type.

Comment: How do you highlight some words like Worker and Human ?

Comment: @UserNam3: Stack Overflow uses Markdown syntax.

Comment: Well I found a way. I just made it into a method or a constructor with parameters like 
public string HumanName(string input1, string input 2).

Comment: @NixeleAdlaon: It's not clear what you mean by that.  But if what you've changed is to remove the `Human` constructor and move its constructor logic to a method then, yes, that would align with the last statement in this answer.  If `Human` has no explicit constructors then it has an implicit parameterless constructor.  So `Worker` would be able to invoke that from its own implicit parameterless constructor.  Any time you create an instance of an inherited type it needs to be able to create an instance of the underlying base type, and parameterless constructors can do exactly that.

Comment: Yeah. sorry about the confusion. I'm still familiarizing myself with the terminologies of c#.

Answer (score 2):

If the constructor of the mother class contains two parameters, the inherited classes must show these two parameters in their constructor. Change as follows:

If value1 and value2 are private, your children cannot acces them.

```
 class Human
 {
      internal string value1;
      internal string value2;
      ...
 }
```

Change the children constructor

```
 class Worker : Human
 {
      public Worker(string input1, string input2) : base(input1, input2)
      {
           value1 = input1;
           value2 = input2;
      }
      ...
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! i just made a constructor and made it into "public string HumanName(string input1, string input2) there still error of "not all code paths return a value. but i think i can manage thank you!

Comment: Why set `value1` and `value2` in *both* constructors?  Calling `base(input1, input2)` already accomplishes this.  `Worker` doesn't need to also do this in the body of its own constructor.